# How are states of matter determined experimentally?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, phase-transition, states-of-matter, phase-diagram

Let's consider for example water. There is the classical phase diagram shown below which depicts the three states liquid, solid, and gaseous. My question is, how were the exact positions of the equilibrium lines determined? In case those are theoretical results, how would one determine them experimentally? I could observe a pot of water while heating it up and then, at some point, observe that some bubbles start to form and, therefore, conclude that the transition to the gaseous phase is about to start, but I imagine that this would be a very inaccurate way to determine the exact moment when that transition happens. The same for freezing: at some point crystals will start to form, but when can it be considered really "solid"? I am interested if there are standardized measurements for determining the state of matter under specific environmental conditions?

[image: Phase diagram of water]
<sub>Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_of_water_simplified.svg</sub>

Comment: the plot you show is a typical plot derived experimentally. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/phase-diagram-determination

Comment: For first order phase transitions one looks for the latent heat signature in a calorimeter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things people typically measure in experiments to diagnose a phase of matter (or critical point / line separating two phases).

1. Conventional phases of matter are diagnosed by the symmetries they respect versus the ones they break spontaneously. This picture is due to Landau. For example, a fluid has continuous translation invariance, in that a point $\vec{x}$ in a fluid is indistinguishable from any point $\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}$. However, a solid forms a crystalline lattice, which spontaneously breaks continuously translation invariance to *discrete* translation invariance --- a point $\vec{x}$ is only equivalent to other points $\vec{x} + n \vec{a}$ where $\vec{a}$ is a lattice translation vector and $n$ is an integer. This crystalline structure can be detected by x rays. Another example is a refrigerator magnet, which is described by a bunch of spins $S_i$. The paramagnetic state is invariant under flipping the north and south poles (i.e., sending $S_i \to -S_i$), but a *ferromagnet* spontaneously breaks this discrete symmetry by forming a magnetic domain with definite north and south poles. The "ordered" phase (the solid or ferromagnet) is characterized by an **order parameter** that vanishes in the disordered phase but is nonzero in the ordered phase. For a magnet the order parameter is the magnetization $\vec{M}$, which spontaneously picks a direction in magnetic materials. For the freezing transition from liquid to solid, the order parameter is related to the density (e.g., x-ray diffraction). This does require having some idea of what the order parameter might be.
2. You can also measure quantities other than order parameters, some of which will also show nonanalytic behavior (e.g., a spike or jump) as a function of some parameter (e.g., temperature). Examples include the heat capacity / specific heat, conductivity, resistivity,  susceptibilities, magnetization, pressure, etc.
3. Some of the above quantities are related to linear response. This is the general way we probe systems experimentally: We apply some perturbation (i.e., we "kick" the system) and then measure the system's response (which we describe theoretically using perturbation theory to "linear" order). Ohm's law is an example of linear response: the current that forms in response to an applied voltage is proportional to that voltage via $V=IR$; more generally, we have $J = \sigma E$, where $J$ is the electromagnetic current, $E$ the electric field, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity tensor. We have similar expressions for the response of a magnet to an applied magnetic field via $M = \chi B$ where $M$ is the magnetization, $B$ the applied magnetic field, and $\chi$ the susceptibility. Different phases of matter have different predictions for how these response functions (e.g., the conductivity $\sigma$ or magnetic susceptibility $\chi$, etc.).
4. In fact, phases of matter are associated with a notion of "universality." These response functions are related to correlation functions (e.g., the spatial correlation $\langle M(x)M(y) \rangle$, the autocorrelation function $\langle M(x,t)M(x,0)\rangle$, or the general correlation function $M(x,t)M(y,0)$). Correlation functions are described by *universal* (or critical) exponents, e.g., $\langle M(x,t)M(0,0) \sim e^{- x^z t}$ for the dynamical exponent $z$. For diffusion, $z=2$. And there are other exponents as well. Basically, if we look at any point in a given phase (in parameter space) and we "coarse grain" (which is a mathematically formal way of "squinting" at a system to ignore very fast and short-distance processes), we get to a "fixed point" whose properties characterize the entire phase. This fixed point describes the longest-distance and longest-time dynamics of the system --- while faster and shorter-range processes may be observed with very fine-tuned probes and the outcomes may differ between experiments, the coarse-grained "universal" properties are there *throughout the entire phase*. These universal properties may be shared by totally different systems --- the phase transition between the ferromagnet and paramagnet described above has the same universal properties as a transition in liquid water! But they diagnose phases very well.

Comment: I think most readers won't understand most of the terms you have introduced.

Comment: You're probably right. Do you think it would help to add links?  Alternatively I can try to elaborate. These terms are all important to understanding the physics of phases of matter.

Comment: I don't think you need complete generality if you don't have time to write a long post. Why not concentrate on a portion? We are a community. Others can fill in what you leave open.

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I'll update the answer later today to include some more explanation and examples.